# Create Enum constant in Flask/Python

Tags: python, flask

Hi I would like to have a file that contain an enum list of all the items I will be using in my configuration. E.G

```
{
  "SUCCESS": 1,
  "FAILED": 1,
  "PENDING": 1,
}
```

I wanted something like in Laravel where in you will only place all your Enum in one of the files. In Laravel I can place this inside the folder config and file list_item e.g

```
return [
  "SUCCESS": 1,
  "FAILED": 1,
  "PENDING": 1,
]
```

so if I reference this in laravel its like config('config.list_item') and this will contain the array that I defined in my list_item file. Is there a way to achieve the same approach in **Python/Flask?** The only way I can think of is creating a file and inside it I will be defining a function like the example below

```
def StatusEnum():
    return {
       "SUCCESS": 1,
       "FAILED": 1,
       "PENDING": 1,
    }
```

and referencing it with **StatusEnum()** but I want to have a cleaner way to this.

So basically I want a cleaner and best approach to have a file that contains all my Enum list. I wan't to know how to do this in python/flask.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to accomplish?

Comment: @LelandBarton edited my question. I wan't something like how Laravel loads and store all config/constants variable (Enum)

Comment: Check [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)

Comment: thanks for asking this question, as a little appreciation I'm upvoting your answer, and the reason I'm telling this in the comment is so that just people would know that they have to upvote a good question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `configparser` from stand library.

```
#config.cfg
[status]
FAILED = 0
SUCCESS = 1
PENDING = 1

# python source code 
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.cfg")
config.getint("status", "FAILED")
```

Or just place a dict variable in your configuration file. Import it where you want to use it.

```
# config.py
status = {"FAILED": 0, "SUCCESS": 1, "PENDING": 2}
```

```
from config import status

print(status["FAILED"])
```

Comment: It seems this is a good idea almost the same with Laravel. I'll accept this as the answer thanks